# Node alignment issue with JsTree

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, jstree

I have an image and text in a JStree node. In other browsers( FF & Chrome) both of them come in the same line. but in IE it comes in differnt lines. one below the other. ( i am using IE 9). in the style sheets i tried using property display : inline-block but the whole JS tree is disturbed even in the other browsers...(this is the case for inner nodes) .. do i have any way out here ??

Initial Output.

IE
 img
 Node text

FF

- img node text - 1

  - img node text -11
  - img node text -12
  - img node text -13

Ch

- img node text - 1

  - img node text -11
  - img node text -12
  - img node text -13

After giving display : inline-block;

IE
 img Node text

FF
 -

- img node text - 1
  -img node text -11 img node text -12 img node text -13

Ch

- img node text - 1
  -img node text -11 img node text -12 img node text -13